# Microsoft Graph Subscriptions of type callRecord POST works but GET fails with error ExtensionError

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I've got an application with the correct permissions (including `CallRecord.Read.All`) and I wanted to add webhook subscriptions for the call records. Implementing the validation flow I found that is not working correctly and I'm receiving errors.

Subscription creation seems to work and returns a `201` and receive a subscription id:

```sh
curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <redacted>' 
-X POST 
-d '{    "notificationUrl": "https://<redacted>.ngrok.io/msft/notifications",    "expirationDateTime": "2021-02-27T10:00:44.603Z",    "resource": "/communications/callRecords",    "changeType": "created",    "clientState": "a-secret"}' 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Location: https://subscriptionstore.windows.net/beta/NA/subscriptions('ef814b3b-<redacted>')
request-id: 0c433a5a-<redacted>
client-request-id: 0c433a5a-<redacted>
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"005","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_12"}}
OData-Version: 4.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2021 12:00:56 GMT
Content-Length: 658

{
"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
"id":"ef814b3b-<redacted>",
"resource":"/communications/callRecords",
"applicationId":"9019a047-<redacted>",
"changeType":"created",
"clientState":"a-secret",
"notificationUrl":"https://<redacted>.ngrok.io/msft/notifications",
"notificationQueryOptions":null,
"notificationContentType":null,
"lifecycleNotificationUrl":null,
"expirationDateTime":"2021-02-27T10:00:44.603Z",
"creatorId":"e911e4f9-<redacted>",
"includeResourceData":null,
"latestSupportedTlsVersion":"v1_2",
"encryptionCertificate":null,
"encryptionCertificateId":null
}
```

However, when trying to `GET` that subscription, I get an error:

```sh
curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <redacted>' 
-X GET 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions/ef814b3b-<redacted>

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 18761dbf-<redacted>
client-request-id: 18761dbf-<redacted>
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_63"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2021 12:01:37 GMT
Content-Length: 318

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "There was an error processing a storage extension.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-02-24T12:01:38",
      "request-id": "18761dbf-<redacted>",
      "client-request-id": "18761dbf-<redacted>"
    }
  }
}
```

I've read about it and double-checked my permissions again, so tried to see if it's a problem getting **that** subscription. I tried instead listing all subscriptions, but I get a `500` error:

```sh
curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <redacted>' 
-X GET 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions/

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: f52ea0ce-<redacted>
client-request-id: f52ea0ce-<redacted>
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_18"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2021 12:05:12 GMT
Content-Length: 292

{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "An unknown error occurred.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-02-24T12:05:13",
      "request-id": "f52ea0ce-<redacted>",
      "client-request-id": "f52ea0ce-<redacted>"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**:
Tried with the `v1.0` endpoints to try to narrow the problem:

- `POST /v1.0/subscriptions` works and creates the resource
- `GET /v1.0/subscriptions/{id}` fails with the same error as the beta endpoint
- `GET/v1.0/subscriptions` does return the full list of subscriptions, including the beta-endpoint created one, and the v1-endpoint created one.

So the subscriptions listing seems to be broken for the `beta` version, and retrieving individual subscriptions for both...

Other relevant bits:

- I've tried with resource values `/communications/callRecords` and `communications/callRecords` just in case, but same results.
- ngrok https tunnel is working because otherwise the initial `POST` fails (MS Graph validates the notificationUrl is alive before the subscription creation process).
- Permissions are granted application-level (not delegated)
- It is an existing and working application just being expanded. It is the first time adding webhook support and change subscriptions, though.
- Tested under [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and trying to GET individual subscriptions have the same errors as via `curl`.

Any hint about what I might be doing wrong, or if there's an ongoing issue with MS Graph with Subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error with the get callRecord Subscription by id.

I suggest you to use the workaround using the get of all Subscriptions and filter the result of the call using you specific Subscription id.